# Do incendiary grenades/molotovs stack damage?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

If a teammate and myself throw an incendiary grenade or molotov at the same spot, does the damage stack for people standing in the area of effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, throwing multiple Molotov Cocktails at the same area will result in stacked damage.

Molotov Cocktails do reasonably high damage and provide effects such as slowing, while being balanced around its price ($850) and easy-to-see visibility which make it easy to counter.

<sup>[Discussion](http://www.teamplayergaming.com/counter-strike-global-offensive/103575-cs-go-set-release-august-21-2012-$15-4.html) | [Another discussion](http://news.esea.net/index.php?s=news&d=comments&id=10471#n24) | [Third discussion](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-2838466.html)</sup>